# How to append to new list item when checking list with for loop?

Tags: python

I am having problems with this and can't figure out why my code is not working. Could someone help me out with this, please? I made this:

```
def f8(a_list, n):
    """
    The parameter a_list is a list of int's. The parameter n is an int.
    The function f8() should return a list that contains exactly one
    of each number in a_list that occurs less than n times in a_list.

    Example:
        f8([1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5], 3) should return
        [1, 5] (as 1 and 5 are the only numbers that occur less than 3
        times in a_list)
    """

    k = []
    for i in a_list:
        if i < a_list.count(n):
            k.append(i)
            return k


print f8([1, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5], 2)
```

I would expect it should print [1,5], but it just gives me a None. Why is that? Could someone help me out, please? I am stuck here.

Comment: Your code tries to find an element of the list which is greater than the count of matches and then, when it does so, makes a 1-element list containing that element. I seriously doubt that this is what you intend, but you don't state the intended behavior, so we can't be certain what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `counting` the wrong way around! You need to count the occurrences of `i` and compare this against `n`. Also, you need to move the `return` outside the `for-loop`. Finally, to remove the repeats in the final `list`, we should iterate through `set(a_list)` so that we only iterate through `unique` `elements`. The neat thing about this is that since we are counting the occurrences in the original `a_list`, we don't need to create any copies or anything fiddly to deal with this.

This makes your `function`:

```
def f8(a_list, n):
    k = []
    for i in set(a_list):
        if a_list.count(i) < n:
            k.append(i)
    return k
```

which works if we give it a test:

```
>>> f8([1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5], 3)
[1, 5]
>>> f8([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7], 3)
[1, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

Note, if you wanted to shorten the `function`, you could achieve the same result in a `one line` `list-comprehension`:

```
def f8(a_list, n):
    return [i for i in set(a_list) if a_list.count(i) < n]
```

which gives the same outputs to the tests as above.

Comment: Did it? ;) I retracted mine after you fixed it.

Comment: Correct. People downvote incorrect answers, and at the time of the downvote, it was incorrect.

Comment: @Sebastian I totally understand.

Comment: @Sebastian People downvote what they deem a bad answer. That may include answers that work, but have unnecessarily bad time-complexity like this one. I might add that this one also doesn't get the "should return a list that contains exactly one" part right.

Comment: Unnecessarily bad time complexity? He's simply editing the solution the OP had, not making it the ideal solution.

Comment: @Sebastian Nowhere near ideal! And see my edited comment

Comment: @schwobaseggl Sorry, I missed that part of the question! My bad. It now iterates through a `set`, so there will be no repeats in the answer...

Comment: @JoeIddon Still this calls `count` multiple times and does not guarantee `[1, 5]` as desired output, but might produce `[5, 1]`,

Comment: @schwobaseggl Good point, it doesn't use any modules though **;)**, I like your answer as well!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should not call `count` repeatedly. Each call iterates the entire list. You can get all counts in one go using `collections.Counter`. Secondly, you need to check if you have added any element before to avoid duplicates, just calling `set` one `a_list` will not guarantee order of appearance:

```
from collections import Counter

def f8(a_list, n):
    c = Counter(a_list)
    k, seen = [], set()
    for x in a_list:
        if c[x] < n and x not in seen:
            seen.add(x)
            k.append(x)
    return k
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition to `append` in your code is never met, thus, no value is being returned. Instead, return after the loop is finished. Also, your counting condition is reversed, as you should be finding the count of `i` occurring in the list, not `n`:

```
k = []
for i in a_list:
    if a_list.count(i) < n and i not in k:
        k.append(i)

return k
```

The reason why you are receiving `None` is that the return statement does not pass, so to satisfy the variable storage during the function call, `None` is returned.